# removing [ and ] from arraylist

Tags: java

I have to print the list values in the form of String. But I am held up with the `[` and `]` in the list. Here is my code.

```
List dbid=new ArrayList();
dbid.add(ar.getdbID());
String check=ar.getdbID().toString();
```

output for the above code :

```
[2, 3,4]
```

But I just need this:

```
2,3,4
```

Comment: one of the reasons I am liking Scala.

Comment: ar.getdbID() what it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use replace method of String class to remove those brackets or you can use regular expression also (i guess regex will be overkill in your case)

Comment: String replace is a bad idea, because some of the List's members could also contain square brackets. The only safe way to post process the String is `string.substring(1, string.length() - 1)`

Answer (score 8):

There are no `[` and `]` "in the List". It's only the `String` representation (produced by `toString()`) that contains those characters. It's important to distinguish those two things.

I'd use a [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) [`Joiner`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```
Joiner.on(',').join(dbid);
```

Of you can manually implement it:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
Iterator<?> it = dbid.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  b.append(it.next());
  if (it.hasNext()) {
    b.append(',');
  }
}
String result = b.toString();
```

Comment: No need for dbid.next().toString(), append(Object) does the same. Otherwise: +1

Comment: @Sean: true, `append(Object)` is even better as it avoids the NPE on `null` values.

Comment: Btw your code doesn't compile. Looks like early morning code :-)

Comment: oops ... yes. It **is** early morning and I still haven't got that Eclipse plugin for SO ;-) at least 4 people didn't mind that, however.

Comment: And I was one of them, took me an hour to notice. Early morning in Berlin, as well

Comment: This code *now* is verified to compile, if `dbid` is an `Iterable`. I will just claim that all of this was done on purpose to demonstrate how much better it is to use pre-made code for this ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[Apache StringUtils join method](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20char%29) is very useful for this:

```
StringUtils.join(new String[] { "1", "2", "3"}, ",");
```

This will return the string "1,2,3"

Comment: There's also `join(Collection)` which might be more suitable, since he's got a `List` already.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better just to iterate through the list. Something like this will do the trick:

```
for(int i=0; i<yourList().size();i++){
                out.println(yourList().get(i));
            }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I agree about a simple iteration doing the trick in this case - anything that prints all values will have to iterate through the list anyway. However, you're currently printing a whole line for each element, whereas the OP wanted them comma-separated. Perhaps you could add that to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Iterator it = dbid.iterator();
if(it.hasNext()){
  sb.append(it.next());
  while(it.hasNext()){
    sb.append(',').append(it.next());
  }
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

toString() function will merely convert the object into its String form. So it is printing the String array as a string in your case. That is why [ ] has come.

You will have to do the following to get your required result.

```
List dbid=new ArrayList();
dbid.add(ar.getdbID());

String[] checks=ar.getdbID();
for(String check:checks) {
    System.out.print(check+" ");
}
System.out.print("\n");
```

Hope you understand the usage.

Answer (score 1):

```
        String pattern = "[\\[\\]]";
        String result = yourstring.replaceAll(pattern, "");
```

This is the best option by far that I have tried and it worked for me.
"yourstring"in this case will be your string object.